# asset_path rails helper using only the dns of assethost given

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Hi following is the how the asset-host is defined.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'cdn.com/site1'
```

Scss file example:

```
.home-ntf-headline.ntf-img {
  background-image: url(asset_path('ntf-logo.png'));
}
```

The actual url frame for above Scss is **cdn.com/assets/ntf-logo-b1a1fa585e8393a621c8ac16d515d96560d469afd8b9aadb36dc290acc4e9c42.png**.

But what i actually expects
**cdn.com/site1/assets/ntf-logo-b1a1fa585e8393a621c8ac16d515d96560d469afd8b9aadb36dc290acc4e9c42.png**.

The static assets in request life cycle(i.e css, js, images) are framed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The "host" here is limited to the top level host, rather than a prefix to the full asset path. If you specify anything after `cdn.com` then it will be stripped before being applied as the `asset_host` in Actionview Helpers.

If you're looking to have multiple sites on the same CDN then you're going to have to look at subdomains rather than paths, or some kind of per-site unique naming convention for your assets (I'd advise against that).